# Pegz Game C# - Help Getting Started

Tags: c#, panel

I was tasked to make a basic Pegz game in C# as an assignment for school. The rules can be found here: http://tinyurl.com/6wro5xc. I'm not looking for a step by step how to build the game, but rather just how to get started. I'm fairly new to C# application development, but have a background in C# web development.

So far I have a flow control layout panel with a 5x5 grid of regular panels within it. Within each regular panel I have a picture box containing the image of the peg. All panels are full except one remains empty. See attached image for an example. In order to keep track of the 5x5 grid of panels I thought I would use a two dimensions BitArray that would hold the coordinates of the panel in the grid, and would be true if a peg exists or false if it does not.

My first question would be how do I go about tieing the grid to the array. In other words: how would I know that [0][0] of the array would represent the top left of the grid? I have the following constructor for the array `BitArray[,] board = new BitArray[5,5];` I know that I will first have to cycle through the array and assign all but one of the values to true, but then I will need to take that data in the array and apply it to the Grid. The concept of how to bind that array to the grid is the part I am stuck at.

I appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you tried it yourself, and if you have problems, post the specific problems.

Comment: I'd try it, the trouble I have is even grasping the concept on how I would tie each panel to the correct location in the array.. Here is the array I constructed: BitArray[,] board = new BitArray[5,5];.

Comment: Then rephrase the question to be more specific.

Comment: Kendall, seems pretty specific to me.  Why is it always necessary for guys like you to shoot down someone's question when you don't know an answer before giving others a chance to?

Comment: That is, if you'd waited 24 hours and no one had answered that would be one thing, but for goodness sake wait at least 60 stinking minutes to see what others have to offer before calling it a bad question.

Comment: At some point, you have to tie the logic to the front-end.  Figure out how to represent the game internally, and then map that logic to your front-end.  How does the game know that `[0][0]` is the top left grid? You tell it to.  Maybe have some sort of loop that updates the game state, and then updates the front-end to reflect that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are undoubtedly better ideas than this one, but nonetheless here's something to get you started...

Instead of making an array of bits, make an array of a class you create to represent a point which will also contain methods to set/unset the point.  Then you could do something like MyGrid[x][y].Set();.

You might also look into using collections instead of arrays too.  I rarely use arrays for anything anymore except low level or legacy type operations that require them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll start looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dyanmic arrays are much faster than MultiDimensional ones, though use the latter if its easier and you know the values. Assuming yo do know the values of each integer in the box it looks like you have a [5][5] two dimensional array. Using .NET and C++ somewhere good to start would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector <int> DynArrNums(25);

DynArrNums[0] = //Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[1] = 1001;
    DynArrNums[2] = 1002;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[3] = 1003;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[4] = 1004;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[5] = 1005;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[6] = 1006;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[7] = 1007;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[8] = 1008;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[9] = 1009;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[10] = 1010;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[11] = 1011;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[12] = 1012;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[13] = 1013;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[14] = 1014;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[15] = 1015;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[16] = 1016;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[17] = 1017;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[18] = 1018;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[19] = 1019;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[20] = 1020;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[21] = 1021;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[22] = 1022;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[23] = 1023;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;
    DynArrNums[24] = 1024;//Put any value here which you know for the rules of your game as a number;

    cout << "Enter another number for the array" << endl;
    int AnotherNum = 0;
    cin >> AnotherNum;
    DynArrNums.push_back(AnotherNum);

    cout << "Number of integers in array: " << DynArrNums.size() << endl;
    cout << "Last element in array: ";
    cout << DynArrNums[DynArrNums.size() - 1] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Remember the first array is stored as 0 which is why the minus 1 is needed at the end. I just tried it and it works :)

However the dynamic array does not specifically need to know your missing integer is the middle panel in the array, it just needs to know you are adding one more. Of course this makes it customisable for your game and you can put any value. In this instance it adds it to the end and you can call any value by its sequence in the array.

To find the number [0] is the first panel [1] is the next panel. [6] would therefore be the 1st panel of line two [11] would be the first in line 3 and so on.

Finally the DynArrNums[25] does not mean you have 25 filled in boxes. It just means their are 25 boxes in your panel and the code knows their is one missing, which is why it asks for it at the end.

Good luck.